# match for types failed on Map

Tags: scala

I'm learning Scala and trying to write some simple code.

When I tried to write a method like this:

```
def func(value: Any) {
  value match {
    case i: Int => println(1)
    case vector: Vector[Any] => println(2)
    case map: Map[Any, Any] => println(3)
    case _ => println(4)
  }
}
```

I got an warn:

```
[warn]........:31: non-variable type argument Any in type pattern scala.collection.immutable.Map[Any,Any] (the underlying of Map[Any,Any]) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
[warn]       case map: Map[Any, Any] => println(3)
[warn]                    ^
[warn] one warning found
```

I am wondering why using `Map[Any, Any]` will get this warn but `Vector[Any]` will not.

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that the first type parameter in the `Map` has no variance while the one in `Vector` is covariant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that a `Map[X, Y]` is not covariant in its type parameter `X` (but a `Vector[X]` is).

What does that mean? Suppose `B <: A` (read, `B` is a subtype of `A`).

Then we have `Vector[B] <: Vector[A]`. That makes sense: If we retrieve an element `x` from a `Vector[B]`, it will be a `B`. That means it is also an `A` by the subtyping relationship. (A similar argument applies to all other methods.)

Following similar reasoning, `Map[X, B] <: Map[X, A]` for all `X` (element retrieval is by key and not index, but essentials remain the same).

However, this doesn't hold for `Map`'s first type parameter. Assume that `Map[B, X] <: Map[A, X]` for some `X`.

We could now do the following:

```
val x: Map[B, X] = ???
x.get(b: B) // makes sense

val y: Map[A, X] = x // must be ok, Map[B, X] <: Map[A, X]
y.get(a: A) // bad! x doesn't know how to "get" with something of type `A`
```

Therefore, a `Map[_, _]` is not necessarily a `Map[Any, Any]`. To fix the error message, use:

```
case map: Map[_, _] => ...
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that `Map` is invariant in its first type parameter. This means that not any map is a sub-type of `Map[Any,Any]`.
On the contrary, `Vector` is covariant in its type parameter, so any `Vector` is always a sub-type of `Vector[Any]`, which means that the compiler does not need to check if the actual runtime type is `Vector[Any]` (which it cannot do anyway due to erasure) as even if it is say a `Vector[String]` it is safe to trat it as a `Vector[Any]`.

Comment: You'd get the same warning for any invariant type (by example when matching for `Set[Any]`)